# iOS Display 'Loading' message before view change

Tags: ios, objective-c, loading

I'm pretty new at this IOS objective C stuff so hopefully this is an easy one.

I have a rightBarButtonItem that when pressed uses a push segue to move to the next view. However, loading that next view takes a while because it involves a database call. I would like the button to change a UILabel (or otherwise alter the UI) to display a message indicating that it is working.

I've tried doing things in the prepareForSegue method, but those changes only take place right before the view changes, if at all.

How should I accomplish what I'm looking for? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you to [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), which puts a nice modal indicator up. It was dead easy to implement.

Take a look this github demo and use into your project. And i also suggest you For better performing  that for process Load Data from DataBase Method in Background using [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) as per your Method:-

for Example in you **ViewDidLoad** Method:-

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];  //Activity Indicator loading

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

           [self LoadDatabae]; //database data fatch method

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES]; //hide that after your Dela Loading finished fromDatabase
            });
        });
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you.

I have a question that has arisen in trying to implement your suggestion. My tableview displays on top of the hud, but everything else works fine.

How can I force the tableview to wait until the async call is done to render?

Comment: you should reload Your Tableview at the end of dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() in this method

Comment: Yeah. I do that, so it looks fine after the async call. The issue is that the spinner is under the table during the async call.

Comment: try with show sur spinner in to Tablview like  [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.yourtableName animated:YES]; instad of [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

Comment: Awesome. I have the HUD showing in viewDidAppear and the async in awakeFromNib. Seems to work. Post your answer here if you want more credits. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343516/view-displaying-on-top-of-loading-icon-due-to-async-call

Comment: its fine @erosebe main things is that you issue was solve...:) and nice work

Answer (score 0):

You should display the loader in any of the following method of Secondviewcontroller.(Where database is called).

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

or

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Edit : I was typing to suggest [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). Thanks for Nitin Gohel.